# Haskell ghciのコマンドをファイルにまとめてバッチ処理

Tags: haskell

ghciをファイルにまとめて、一括処理することはできますか？例えば、

test.hs

```
   1+2
   3*5
```

というファイルを入力して、ghciから以下のような出力を得たいです。

```
    Prelude> 1+2
    3
    Prelude> 3*5
    15
    Prelude>
```

試しに、以下のコマンドや、ghciのインタラクティブモードで :l test.hsなどを試しましたが、すべてParse error: naked expression at top levelというエラーがでて、上記のような結果は得られませんでした。

```
    ghci test.hs
    runghc test.hs
```

Comment: なぜそれをしたいのかが気になります．こういうことをするのは稀な気がするので，その情報があるとより親切な回答がつきやすい（質問への直接的な回答以上の何か的な）…かも．

Comment: `ghci < test.hs` だとだめですか

Answer (score 3):

コマンドを常に実行させたいならば,カレントディレクトリに置いた`.ghci`ファイルにコマンドを書き,ghciを引数無しで実行すれば自動的に読み込まれます.
ファイルを分けたいならば,`test.ghci`などとファイルを作って`ghci -ghci-script test.ghci`で実行すると良いです.
こういうファイルはghci scriptと呼ばれるもので,Haskellソースではありませんので当然loadするとコンパイルエラーが出ます.

Answer (score 2):

結果だけでいいなら `:s` (`:script`)というのがありますが。

```
Prelude> :s test.hs
3
15
Prelude>
```